# Update data subscribed to without starting another cycle

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am getting data from a ngrx/store
I am subscribing to the data

```
this.store.select(somedataList)
  .subscribe(myList => {

  myList.propertyA = "a different value";

});
```

Once I have subscribed and changed the property values I need to I update the data in the store.

```
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateSomeDataList(myList));
```

Once I call "dispatch" the ".subscribe" kicks off again and creates an endless loop.

How can I update the data without creating an endless loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a subscription to fire only once - use `take(1)/first()` RxJS's operators

```js
this.store.select(somedataList).pipe(take(1))
```

and in this case, your subscription would unsubscribe after the first value

Calling dispatch after subscribing for same store's part - it would be *looped*, so you need to rethink your **data flow**